# how to install lprotobuf-c in ubuntu for c language

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compiler-construction, makefile

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf-c
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_apl] Error 1
```

These are the errors I'm getting.

I have installed `apt-get install protobuf-c-compiler`, but `makefile` is still not running.

Comment: You want to install `libprotobuf-c0`, to get this library. `apt-cache search protobuf` would have helped in this case, hinting at a `Protocol Buffers C library`

Answer (score 3):

[Right installation process](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) for `protobuf-c-compiler` which require
                 When compiling under Ubuntu `(12.04 LTS)`, you will need the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libxml2-dev libgeos++-dev libpq-dev libbz2-dev proj libtool automake
```

If you want `PBF` read support, you will also need `libprotobuf-c0-dev` and `protobuf-c-compiler`:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-c0-dev protobuf-c-compiler
```

`libprotobuf-c0-dev` needs to be at least in `version 0.14-1. Ubuntu <= 10.04` has only `0.11`, so you need to build it from source. To compile from source:

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev libprotoc-dev
svn checkout http://protobuf-c.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ protobuf-c-read-only
cd protobuf-c-read-only
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

After that, follow the from source [instructions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#From_source_.28generic.29).

**For Linking error:**
Linking of `libprotobuf-c.so` failing while building [executable.](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/issues/detail?id=73)